# Top N products type in every month - BIGQUERY

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, top-n

I have to create a TOP 10 of gross revenue/country/month with the statement :

dimensions:

- date (month)
- site_country
- product type

metric:
gross_revenue (only top 10 products type per country/month)

I have tried a big query program below between 2 tables :

SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m",t0.order_create_date) AS month,
t0.site_country AS country,
p0.product_type AS product,
SUM(t0.item_sale_price) AS gross_revenue

FROM `transactions` t0
LEFT JOIN `products` p0
ON t0.item_id = p0.item_id
where rn <= 10
ORDER BY
month ASC
LIMIT

I also tried this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSABk.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY gross_revenue DESC) AS rn
from(
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m",t0.order_create_date) AS month,
       t0.site_country AS country,
       p0.product_type AS product,
       SUM(t0.item_sale_price) AD gross_revenue
FROM transactions t0
  LEFT JOIN products p0 ON t0.item_id = p0.item_id)x )xx
  where rn <= 10
```

Comment: how could I make a top 10 product type/country/month between 2 tables  ? (the key is item_id)    SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m",t0.order_create_date) AS month,
  t0.site_country AS country,
  p0.product_type AS product,
  SUM(t0.item_sale_price) AD gross_revenue,
FROM
  `transactions` t0
LEFT JOIN
  `products` p0
ON
  t0.item_id = p0.item_id
ROW_NUMBER(OVER (partition by'gross_revenue'))
ORDER BY
'country/month'DESC
LIMIT
  10    BIGquery result : Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "gross_revenue" at [5:30]

Comment: It doesn't work SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY gross_revenue DESC) AS rn,
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m",t0.order_create_date) AS month,
  t0.site_country AS country,
  p0.product_type AS product,
  SUM(t0.item_sale_price) AS gross_revenue
FROM
  `transactions` t0
LEFT JOIN
  `products` p0
ON
  t0.item_id = p0.item_id
WHERE
  rn <= 10
LIMIT
  10

Comment: Unrecognized name: rn at [14:3]

Comment: try now, i edited

Comment: I've tried again : Syntax error: Unexpected end of script at [16:6]

Comment: What platform do you use ?

Comment: google big query